# Disable button for 30 seconds and show countdown

Tags: c#

I am New in C#

I want to disable a button for 30 seconds after clicking it and then enable it again.

I found the following code but there isn't a live countdown.

I want to display a countdown from 30 to 0, but I can't make it. I can't post comments because I'm new to SO and I need at least 50 reputation to do that.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
// event handler of your button

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{                
    timer.Interval = 30000; // here time in milliseconds
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();
    button1.Enabled = false;

    // place get random code here
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = true;
    timer.Stop();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Want a button to disable for 30 second after click and enable it automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717982/want-a-button-to-disable-for-30-second-after-click-and-enable-it-automatically)

Comment: @YashKaranke It's more than a duplicate. His code is identical to the accepted answer on that question. Mohamed, what's wrong with this code?

Comment: Yeah @john I just saw the answer on that post and he copied the exact same code from there.

Comment: Mohamed, you can set the interval to 1000, and then simply define a class-level integer variable (like timer) and count to 30 using that. Then you can update some text field on each tick of the timer.

Comment: I can't post comments because I'm new  and I need at least 50 reputation to do that.  :(  and i want the same code but some small modifction to it

Comment: Mohamed, try what I suggested. That should work for you.

Comment: thanks john i even cant explain the problem to get the exact solution  i am now 2 hours to get the text look like count down but it is not working .... i make that  but after it work for once the second time i click the button it is not work   ...

Comment: hi @john , the hole program has crash and i cant fix it , and i make the hole new version of the program and your code work just very fine to me and it count down by 1 now .. and to be honest i don't know what was the problem exactly to count down by 2 at first.. thank you so much again  a lot of people help me but no one was understands what i need like you , i have a lot of tasks i want to make in the program and i am sure i will ask here ..so i hope you to answer it .. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a countdown variable, and made the interval 1 second. In the tick method, we decrement the countdown until we reach 0, and then we re-enable the button. If countdown > 0, we output the remaining seconds to the output window (I've no idea how you want to use this value).

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
int countdown = 30;
// event handler of your button

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    countdown = 30; // number of seconds
    timer.Interval = 1000; // one second
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();
    button1.Enabled = false;

    // place get random code here
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (--countdown <= 0)
    {
        button1.Enabled = true;
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Tick -= timer_Tick;
    }
    else
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Remaining: {0}s", countdown));
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much  it is work know  and thank you to answer to me with this code

Comment: it is count down by 2 but it is fine to me :) thank you again

Comment: @Eng.MohamedBassuny You're welcome. I could see you'd done some research into your problem, and nobody else was giving an answer  :) Re counting down in 2s: If you're updating a label, you might want to call .Refresh() on the label after you update its value, so that it redraws.

Comment: yes i search and try it with Different ways but it work in the first and in second time stop and not work again ... it is actually not label it is "lblStripStatus" and i cant find the Refresh() with it but i will try it again ....:D  the C# will kill me Like this :D

Answer (score 1):

one of the simplest way to achieve above problem.

```
async void disableButton()
{
            btn.IsEnabled = false;
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            btn.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Comment: I believe Mohamed wants to show a countdown in the interim.